# GPIO interrupt triggered by different pin

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, gpio

tl;dr:

Listening to a RISING event on GPIO PIN14 (with 10K pulldown resistor); Ghost RISING events when sending/receiving data on different GPIO pin;

---

I have the following issue:

In my technical room I have a Raspberry Pi 1B, and Raspberry Pi 3; I tested this on both units and I get the same results;

My mains meter has a flashing LED, 1000/kWh; I want to measure this using a photo resistor; The photo resistor is connected to GPIO PIN14; This setup works just fine, as long as I don't use any of the other GPIO pins.

Using the same unit I want to send some data over 433Mhz (GPIO PIN7, but as soon as I transmit data, I get RISING events on PIN14...

Across the internet I found different solutions, none of which seem to be working:

- Use a different Raspberry Pi (B1 is a tad bit old)
- Use a 10K pull down resistor on PIN14
- Use a different power supply
- Use separate power supplies for the raspberry pi, photo resistor, and 433Mhz transmitter

Using the code below, I can see expected behavior of the photo resistor and PIN14; But as soon as I startup the transmissions, the events of sending a message and RISING events on PIN14 synchronize. When I stop sending messages the listener on PIN14 stops working.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

[image: Diagram]

PIN14 Listener code:

```
import datetime
import time

try:
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
except RuntimeError:
    print(
        'Error importing RPi.GPIO!  This is probably because you need superuser privileges.')

delta = datetime.timedelta(microseconds=100000)
global last_electric_ping
last_electric_ping = datetime.datetime.now()

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(14, GPIO.IN)


def electric_ping(channel):
    if GPIO.input(14):
        global last_electric_ping
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        if delta + last_electric_ping <= now:
            print(delta + last_electric_ping, end=" ")
            print('ELECTRIC')
        last_electric_ping = now

GPIO.add_event_detect(14, GPIO.RISING, callback=electric_ping)

while True:
    continue

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Transmission code:

```
import time
from pi_switch import RCSwitchSender

sender = RCSwitchSender()
sender.enableTransmit(15) # use WiringPi pin 0

num = 1
while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Woei!")
        sender.sendDecimal(num, 24)
        num += 1
```

Comment: Interesting - I like your setup :) Have been using the cheap 433 MHz transmitters/receivers a lot too. Never had any interference issues though. I wonder if it's the transmitter pin or the radio waves themselves causing the disturbance. What if you disconnect the transmitter but still try to send a signal via `WiringPi pin 0`? Stronger pulldown on pin 14, maybe? (shouldn't be necessary but you could try 5K or so). Maybe add a debounce period of 100-200 ms to `GPIO.add_event_detect`? Just some things to try out.

Comment: I tried to do a debounce by doing a
delta = datetime.timedelta(microseconds=100000)

I just checked the layout of the board, and apparently the GPIO PIN14 is a UART(?) pin; This evening I'll try to shuffle the pins around a little bit, maybe that improves things.

Sending events to non connected ports doesn't trigger this behaviour.

Comment: UART is a serial connection; it's found on lots of stuff. It can be used to hook up an arduino, for instance. Good idea to try different pins and see if the response changes. Try adding the debounce via RPI.GPIO's `bouncetime` option: `GPIO.add_event_detect(14, GPIO.RISING, callback=electric_ping, bouncetime=200)`.
*"Sending events to non connected ports doesn't trigger this behaviour."* So it might be the transmitter? Put it in a plastic bag and wrap it in tinfoil! :D

Comment: jDo, thanks for thinking along side me; I could've sworn I switched pins around before I posted this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roll the drums:

Apparently I ran into a numbering issue; The BCM pin numbering says physical pin 8 is GPIO14, which is nice;

Now three guesses which number wiringPi gives to physical pin number 8... yes, number 15! Which is the one I'm trying send data to in the second script;

Now excuse while I go slap myself with a brick in the corner over there...

Comment: d'oh! :D Glad you sorted it out!